# visual studio does not show git history

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have recently faced on a error . it is so weird .
I can see whole logs in git bash but I cannot see them in Visual studio 2022.

in the attached picture, you can see $git log command and the error that I got from visual studio 2022.

[image]

please let me know if you know any workarounds.

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-view-history-fails-with-fatal-error/1266043), some people have resolved this by opening `git-gui` from the command line, and then selecting Repository->Compress database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible there is some sort of minor corruption in the repo. Try opening `git-gui` from the command line and then selecting "Repository->Compress database".

The idea to try this came from a [Visual Studio developer community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-view-history-fails-with-fatal-error/1266043) discussing this same issue.